# Is there a cohomology for magmas?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, cohomology, non-associative-algebras

Is there a cohomology theory for magmas? Or cohomology theories for any class of non-associative algebras (other than Lie and maybe Jordan)?

Comment: Isn't there a cohomology for algebras over any operad?

Answer (score 8):

Fernando is right, magmatic algebras are algebras over the magma operad. This operad is free, it is generated by a bilinear operation.

We can define André-Quillen cohomology of magmatic algebras: the situation is very nice because the magma operad is Koszul.

If you like homotopical algebra you can produce a closed model category of simplicial or differential graded magmatic algebras (of $R$-modules) and produce André-Quillen homology as the derived functor of indecomposable elements and so forth and so on...

Comment: Thnaks to all  - I should have thought of that - must be getting rusty

Comment: but Andre-Quillen means going simplicial - because R could be over charateristic p?

Comment: There is no problem with the characteristic because the operad is free, you can work in the dg setting.

Answer (score 3):

Eilenberg S., Mac Lane S., Algebraic cohomology groups and loops, Duke Math. J.
**14** (1947), 435-463.

Johnson K.W., Leedham-Green C.R., Loop cohomology, Czech. Math. J. **40** (1990),
182-194.

Comment: They asked for magmas, not necc. quasigroups...